# How to Generate an E-mail Message in Microsoft Outlook Outbox in VB6?

Tags: email, vb6, outlook, automation

I need to send e-mails from my application. But, instead of sending the e-mails directly from through SMTP, I'd like to send it through Microsoft Outlook. So...

**How to Generate an E-mail Message in Microsoft Outlook Outbox in VB6?**

Comment: Be aware that if your code does anything that might make Outlook think you're a macro virus (such as trying to access the Address Book), the user will be presented with a dialog box. Have a look at Outlook Redemption ( http://www.dimastr.com/redemption )if you get that problem.

Comment: Answered on stackoverflow:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769763/email-using-access-and-vba-without-mapi

Answer (score 2):

This [support page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/220595) from Microsft has examples.

```
Send a message to your new contact.
   Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
   Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
 ' Fill out & send message...
   olMail.To = olItem.Email1Address
   olMail.Subject = "About our meeting..."
   olMail.Body = _
        "Dear " & olItem.FirstName & ", " & vbCr & vbCr & vbTab & _
        "I'll see you in 2 minutes for our meeting!" & vbCr & vbCr & _
        "Btw: I've added you to my contact list."
   olMail.Send
```

Answer (score 2):

Use COM automation. This [KnowledgeBase article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/161088) explains how to do it from VBA, it's exactly the same in VB6. The References command is on the Project menu in VB6 not the Tools menu, I think that's the only difference. EDIT: [This KnowledgeBase article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/220595) explains how to do it in VB6. Kudos to Shoban for this, upvote [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975147/how-to-generate-an-e-mail-message-in-microsoft-outlook-outbox-in-vb6/975191#975191) not mine!

I think the MSDN topic [Automating Outlook from a Visual Basic applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa209963(office.11).aspx) is also worth mentioning just for Microsoft's typo in the title!

Answer (score 0):

Add a project reference to the Microsoft Outlook X Object Library

Then, in a form, module, class, or whatever ... I chose a button_click event.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
  Dim objMail As MailItem

  Dim strToAddress As String
  Dim strSubject As String
  Dim strBody As String

  Set objOutlook = New Outlook.Application
  Set objMail = Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

  strToAddress = "me@mydomain.com"
  strSubject = "VB6 test email"
  strBody = "This is a test email sent from VB6"

  With objMail
    .To = strToAddress
    .Subject = strSubject
    .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
    .Body = strBody
  End With

  MsgBox "outlook security will now complain as I try to resolve your email addresses against your address book"
  objMail.Recipients.ResolveAll

  objMail.Save
  Set objMail = Nothing
  Set objOutlook = Nothing

  MsgBox "look in your drafts folder for the new email"

  'Thank you, I'm here all week, try the Veal. Good night.
End Sub
```